# primefaces barchart X axis decimal tick labels with single decimal digit

Tags: primefaces, jqplot

How can I get decimal tick labels on X axis

the decimal values should have only one decimal digit.

can I achieve it?

please suggest me

thank u

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `extender` of the `<p:barChart` , like this:

```
<p:barChart value="#{myBean.myModel}" widgetVar="myBarChart" extender="my_ext"/>


<script type="text/javascript">
    function my_ext() {
        this.cfg.axes.xaxis.tickOptions = {
            formatString : '%#.1f'
        };
    }
</script>
```

Comment: :I already tried this. %d indicates integers. But I need decimals with single digit

Comment: try `%#d` or `#%d` or `%1d`

Comment: :One more Question: How can I display data value on the bar in primefaces barChart?

Comment: Not sure how to do it , but anyway, accept this answer and ask a new one... so the answer to the new question wont get lost...

Comment: I already asked that question and waiting for answer. Anyway thank u